# Write custom string value into SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall with Inno Setup

Tags: installation, registry, inno-setup

During installation, I'd like to write a custom string value into the automatically created registry key `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\MyApp.2020_is1`

I tried to do this in the `[Registry]` section of my iss script but it seems to be ignored.

```
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{#MyAppName}.{#MyAppVersion}_is1"; ValueData: "some tag"; Flags: uninsdeletekey; ValueType: string; ValueName: "CustomTag"
```

Is this generally discouraged or am I missing something particular?
I do have `PrivilegesRequired=admin` in the `[Setup]` section.

With the possibility to install multiple builds of my app side-by-side, I want to give the user the possibility to add a descriptive tag so that they can identify the build not only via build number but also the tag.

As I'm searching the registry for previous builds anyways, I was trying to add a custom value into the uninstall key instead of having to reference another key to find the custom tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Uninstall` entry is created as one of the last steps of the installation. So also after the `[Registry]` section is processed. Check the [Installation order](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=installorder). And when the entry is created, its previous contents is completely removed, including your `some tag` value.

As @Bill_Stewart already commented, the correct way is to use [`SetPreviousData`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_setpreviousdata)/[`GetPreviousData`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_getpreviousdata).

If you really wanted to use your own custom code to write the entry, you will have to do it from Pascal Script in [`CurStepChanged(ssPostInstall)` event](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurStepChanged) (triggered after the `Uninstall` entry is created).

---

If you want to allow users to distinguish the installation, the tag must go to [`AppName`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_appname) or [`AppVerName`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_appvername) or [`UninstallDisplayName`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_uninstalldisplayname).

If you need to allow parallel installations, the installations must have different [`AppId`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_appid) – which is a part of the uninstaller key name, so no additional tag should be needed.